# how to identify business card profile picture using Android OCR

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, ocr

I have a native android mobile application. I want to scan user profile picture inside the business card and retrieve that image in my mobile application. How can I do that processes?

Comment: Can u add an example of a scanned name

Comment: For a simple answer, just split the string the name is in around the ' ' character.  That will work for most names.  Of course it won't work for asian names (where the last name comes first) or first names that have multiple words (think Bobby Joe).  Which is why if you need first and last you should have them enter them that way.

Comment: @IndexOutOfBoundsException  "Jason Brave" is the name  Jason is the First name and Brave is the last name. Can you given any sample code. Because I am beginner for the mobile app development.

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you given any sample code. Because I am beginner for the mobile app development.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using Eclipse, might help.

```
    //split string and store in array
    String[] info = acc.split(" ");
    //assign the element of the array
    String fName = info[0];
    String lName = info[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Full Name consist of First Name and Last Name separated by space, you can split your full name using " " to get First Name and Last Name.

Example:

```
    String fullName = "Jason Brave";
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    
    String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
    if(names.length > 0)
        firstName = names[0];
    
    if(names.length > 1)
        lastName = names[1];
```